# remove 1st item (or any item) form multivalued parameter item list in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reportparameter

I have a multivalued parameter named as Graduation_Year.  It is a **optional parameter**. So I have used the "Please Select" as the default with value 0. Therefore I have used below query to make it optional and filter values only when a real value is entered.

```
 EH.Pwks_year_of_graduation IN (@GradYear) OR 0 IN (@GradYear)
```

[image]

But here user has to de- select "Please Select" get the correct result.

I tried to filter the Graduation_Year parameter using dataset parameter expressions. But it didn't work. 
Please suggest a method to filter out the 1st item in the multivalued parameter list (it can be used with below expression).

```
=iif((Parameters!GradYear.Value(0)="0" And Parameters!GradYear.Count>1)
,**Filtered Parameter value list**
,Parameters!GradYear.Value)
```

All I want is to remove Parameters!GradYear.Value(0), 
when Parameters!GradYear.Count>1 
form the multivalue parameter before it is considered in the query.

Thanks
Mathee

Answer (score 0):

You have started off the wrong foot and now you are trying to fix something you shouldn't have done anyway.

The provided value `**Please Select**` should be a prompt and not a specified value for your parameter.

If you go to the parameter properties there is a property called `Prompt` specify `Please select` there.

[image]

Now when you execute the report it will show the parameter as follow:

[image]

Comment: No this is not about parameter prompt. I use "Please Select" in a way similar to (NULL). Any way in your example user has to provide a value for parameter. So this is not a optional parameter. I have made my parameter optional by setting default value that doesn't make sense.